# Data value of array not printing properly

Tags: perl

I have written a script which collects marks of students and print the one who scored above `50`.

Script is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my @array = (
'STUDENT1,90
STUDENT2,40
STUDENT3,30
STUDENT4,30
');

print Dumper(\@array);

my $class = "3";

foreach my $each_value (@array) {
    print "EACH: $each_value\n";

    my ($name, $score ) = split (/,/, $each_value);

    if ($score lt 50) {
        next;
    } else {
        print "$name, \"GOOD SCORE\", $score, $class";
    }
}
```

Here I wanted to print data of STUDENT1, since his score is greater than 50.
So output should be:

```
STUDENT1, "GOOD SCORE", 90, 3
```

But its printing output like this:

```
STUDENT1, "GOOD SCORE", 90
STUDENT2, 3
```

Here some manipulation happens between `90 STUDENT2` which it discards to separate it.

I know I was not splitting data with new line character since we have single element in the array `@array`.

How can I split the element which is in array to new line, so that inside for loop I can split again with comma(`,`) to have the values in `$name` and `$score`.

Actually the `@array` is coming as an argument to this script. So I have to modify this script in order to parse right values.

Comment: "_Actually the `@array` is coming as an argument to this script_"  -- how exactly?  Need to "modify" for that anyway, right?  So let's come up with a solution including that as well

Comment: @zdim thanks a lot for your concern. I did a mistake actually. The argument was `scalar` and I made it as an `array`. `my @array = split (/\|/, $data_value);` where as I said `$data_value` is argument for me. Anyway [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62332529/6124824) answer fixed my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already know your "array" only has one "element" with a string with the actual records in it, so it essentially is more a scalar than an array.

And as you suspect, you can split this scalar just as you already did with the newline as a separator instead of a comma. You can then put a `foreach` around the result of `split()` to iterate over the records.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my $records = 'STUDENT1,90
STUDENT2,40
STUDENT3,30
STUDENT4,30
';

my $class = "3";

foreach my $record (split("\n", $records)) {
  my ($name, $score) = split(',', $record);

  if ($score >= 50) {
    print("$name, \"GOOD SCORE\", $score, $class\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: You can, of course, use the `qq( ... )` operator to avoid having to escape the double-quotes inside your double-quoted string.

Comment: @zdim: Yes, you're right, I blindly redid the OPs mistake. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

As a small note, `lt` is a string comparison operator. The numeric comparisons use symbols, such as `<`.

---

Although you have an array, you only have a single string value in it:

```
my @array = (
'STUDENT1,90
STUDENT2,40
STUDENT3,30
STUDENT4,30
');
```

That's not a big deal. [Dave Cross has already shown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62332529/2766176) you have you can break that up into multiple values, but there's another way I like to handle multi-line strings. You can open a filehandle on a reference to the string, then read lines from the string as you would a file:

```
my $string = 'STUDENT1,90
STUDENT2,40
STUDENT3,30
STUDENT4,30
';

open my $string_fh, '<', \$string;
while( <$string_fh> ) {
    chomp;
    ...
    }
```

One of the things to consider while programming is how many times you are duplicating the data. If you have it in a big string then split it into an array, you've now stored the data twice. That might be fine and its usually expedient. You can't always avoid it, but you should have some tools in your toolbox that let you avoid it.

And, here's a chance to use [indented here docs](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2016/12/strip-leading-spaces-from-here-docs-with-v5-26/):

```
use v5.26;
my $string = <<~"HERE";
    STUDENT1,90
    STUDENT2,40
    STUDENT3,30
    STUDENT4,30
    HERE

open my $string_fh, '<', \$string;
while( <$string_fh> ) {
    chomp;
    ...
    }
```

For your particular problem, I think you have a single string where the lines are separated by the '|' character. You don't show how you call this program or get the data, though.

You can choose any line ending you like by setting the value for the input record separator, `$/`. Set it to a pipe and this works:

```
use v5.10;

my $string = 'STUDENT1,90|STUDENT2,40|STUDENT3,30|STUDENT4,30';

{
local $/ = '|';   # input record separator
open my $string_fh, '<', \$string;
while( <$string_fh> ) {
    chomp;
    say "Got $_";
    }
}
```

Now the structure of your program isn't too far away from taking the data from standard input or a file. That gives you a lot of flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

The `@array` contains one element, Actually the `for loop` will working correct, you can fix it without any change in the `for` block just by replacing this array:

```
my @array = (
'STUDENT1,90',
'STUDENT2,40',
'STUDENT3,30',
'STUDENT4,30');
```

Otherwise you can iterate on them by splitting lines using new line  `\n` .